# Failure to compile R Rspectra package on CentOS 7 in a Virtualbox

Tags: r, linux, virtualbox, centos7, r-package

I'm trying to install the R RSpectra package on a CentOS 7 installation in a VirtualBox but the installation hangs. Here's some system info from the shell and R terminals:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/*-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
[vagrant@localhost ~]$


> Sys.info()
                             sysname                              release
                             "Linux"         "3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64"
                             version                             nodename
"#1 SMP Fri Mar 3 00:04:05 UTC 2017"              "localhost.localdomain"
                             machine                                login
                            "x86_64"                            "vagrant"
                                user                       effective_user
                              "root"                               "root"

> as.matrix(R.Version())
               [,1]
platform       "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu"
arch           "x86_64"
os             "linux-gnu"
system         "x86_64, linux-gnu"
status         ""
major          "3"
minor          "3.2"
year           "2016"
month          "10"
day            "31"
svn rev        "71607"
language       "R"
version.string "R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)"
nickname       "Sincere Pumpkin Patch"
```

And here's the R console output showing that installation hangs:

```
> install.packages("RSpectra", quiet=FALSE, verbose=TRUE)
Installing package into '/usr/lib64/R/library'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
system (cmd0): /usr/lib64/R/bin/R CMD INSTALL
trying URL 'https://cran.uni-muenster.de/src/contrib/RSpectra_0.12-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'unknown' length 426762 bytes (416 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 416 KB

foundpkgs: RSpectra, /tmp/RtmpYHq9lV/downloaded_packages/RSpectra_0.12-0.tar.gz
files: /tmp/RtmpYHq9lV/downloaded_packages/RSpectra_0.12-0.tar.gz
During startup - Warning message:
Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C"
* installing *source* package 'RSpectra' ...
** package 'RSpectra' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/RcppEigen/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c eigs_gen.cpp -o eigs_gen.o
```

Because the installation hangs, I don't know where to start looking for the error. I solved previous R package installation issues on another platform by using:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev 
sudo apt-get install -y libxml2-dev
```

I'm hoping there is a similar solution for RSpectra.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by allocating more memory to the VM using the Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
#   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
#   vb.gui = true
#
#   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
vb.memory = "4096"
end
```